# R: My calculated cumulative sample distribution probabilities don't reach 1.0

Tags: r, distribution, sample, group, ecdf

I want to calculate the cumulative probabilities for my sample **for each factor level** and save them to a data frame.
However, the **calculated probabilites don't reach 1.0** and stop e.g. at 0.7 which cannot be true.
Somehow it always reaches 1.0 only for one group.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(datasets)

ecdf_fun <- ecdf(iris$Sepal.Width)

dset <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>%
  reframe(ecdval = ecdf_fun(Sepal.Width))
```

Which delivers:

```
    Species    ecdval
1   setosa     1.000000000
2   setosa     0.993333333
...
51  versicolor 0.833333333
52  versicolor 0.753333333
...
101 virginica  0.960000000
102 virginica  0.960000000
```

ADD-ON:
Ideally, I would like to retrieve the cumulative probabilites in combination with their respective x values (Sepal.Width).

```
    Species    ecdval       Sepal.Width
1   setosa     1.000000000  0.6
2   setosa     0.993333333  ...
...
51  versicolor 0.833333333  1.8
52  versicolor 0.753333333  ...
...
101 virginica  0.960000000  2.5
102 virginica  0.960000000  ...
```

Comment: You are calculating the `ecdf` on the whole dataset but then grouping it to create `dset`, so it is not surprising that only one group contains the maximum value (i.e. the ecdf reaches 1.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrew Gustar says the `ecdf()` needs to be grouped. Then use mutate to keep the original data along with the cdf?

```
dset <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(ecdval = ecdf(Sepal.Width)(Sepal.Width))

ggplot(dset, aes(Sepal.Width, ecdval, col=Species)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Great, this works! Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.
Could you please tell me why there are two brackets, I am not familiar with this syntax:  "ecdf(Sepal.Width)(Sepal.Width)"
I couldn't find an explanation online and it should be useful for the future.

Comment: `ecdf(x)` returns a function (as in your code in the question) so `ecdf(x)(x)` returns the value of that function at each value of `x`